# Selenium grid, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, selenium, grid

I wanted to start Hub and node using selenium-server standalone jar. Command used are right. I m able to start hub and rc nodes on 3 machines. Whereas in 4th machine, i used the same jar  with the same commands.Its throwing, I'm getting following error

```
org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty()Z
at org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.getRemoteControlConfiguration(RegistrationRequest.java:552)
at org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote.startRemoteServer(SelfRegisteringRemote.java:85)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:72)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where did you get that *jar* file?

Comment: what Java Runtime are you using, isEmpty() was introduce in jdk 6

Comment: jar file from seleniumhq.org .. downloaded selenium-server-stadalone-2.14.0.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The isEmpty() method was introduced in java 6.  If you are using a version of java that is older, then perhaps thats where the error is coming from.